# In Ubuntu 22.04- how do I issue my password in a startup application that requires a sudo?

Tags: gnome, mount, sudo, fstab, autostart

I have a couple of network folders in other linux machines on my CIFS network.
I've set them in **FSTAB** and they are accessed OK, ***PROVIDING*** I do a **sudo mount -a** when the system is restarted.
I've managed to put the mount -a in a gnome-terminal app invoked by my .config/autostart, but the gnome-terminal (sudo) then asks for my password.
How can I provide my password in the  Desktop entry in this autostart?
EG:
`Exec=gnome-terminal --tab --title="FSTABBER INITIATE!" --command="bash -c  'sudo mount -a;  echo DID OUR FSTABBER WORK OK?; $SHELL'"`

(Don't worry- I'll get rid the extraneous echo and $SHELL once it works successfully)
An alternative might be to put me in a sudoers file, but I'd rather do a sudo whenever I actually need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper way to achieve this.

- You should never have "sudo" in a startup application for your desktop. Instead, you should start a command that configures your system properly using a systemd service, or, way easier, using the root's crontab.
- Alternatively, configure your mount options so you can mount as a user. Then the autostart script can do that without needing an administrator password.
- Prefer also to mount just your target file system instead lazily using "sudo mount-a" and having the system process the entire fstab file again.

While there are methods to feed a password automatically to the mount command, it is bad practice from a security point of view.